# How can I play play custom MP3 file in echo show 5/ Alexa device?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I have ECHO show 5 device at my home. I have a mp3 file on my smartphone which I want to play on my voice command by amazon ECHO.
I am ok to upload this file if echo can support it.
How can I do this activity with alexa?

Note : I am aware about Bluetooth pair option but is there any other way.

Comment: Which device do expect to handle the voice command, the phone or the Echo Show?

Comment: Hi hardlib, I have edited the question itself to avoid the confusion

Comment: OK, so this has nothing to do with the phone (apart from that is where the file currently is)

Comment: Yes, if I can have the file on phone and still play it on echo then it will be really really great but I don`t see any way as of now for that apart from bluetooth

Comment: Do we really do not have capability to do so in AI age? Shame on amazon :(